# sudo: unknown user: root via PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I'm using PythonAnywhere with Postgresql, and have run into several problems. When I try to do anything, such as `python manage.py makemigrations`, I get the following error :

> sudo: unknown user: root
>
> sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Also, I tried to use `postgres -V`, but I get `command not found`, and yet I can't use `sudo` to install it.

Finally, I'm also not sure what my UNIX password is, but all my permissions are denied to me.

Strangely, I've noticed the creation of a `dead.letter` file, which contains:

> giles-liveconsole1 : Feb 17 09:25:05 : X : user NOT in sudoers ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/X/X/X ; USER=X ; COMMAND=/bin/bash
>
> giles-liveconsole2 : Feb 17 11:43:08 : X : user NOT in sudoers ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/etc ; USER=#0 ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/vi /etc/passwd
>
> giles-liveconsole2 : Feb 17 11:45:51 : X : user NOT in sudoers ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/etc ; USER=#0 ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/vi /etc/passwd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was within my settings.py - I wasn't pointing the project to the correct database settings - username and password. I changed the settings to reflect those of my pythonanywhere details, and then I could operate manage.py properly from there.

Answer (score 3):

In general, makemigrations should not be using sudo. If it is, then there's something in your django settings that's making it do that.

You don't need to run postgres - it's already running. See the Databases tab in your account for the connection details.